# SOLID Open/Closed - Interface Segregation Principles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solid-principles, open-closed-principle

I have applied the Open/Closed principle on the code I am currently working on. The example is given here:

```
def error_response(object)
      return { errs: object.to_s, status_code: :internal_server_error,
      has_error: true } if object.is_a?(Exception)
      { errs: object.errors.full_messages.as_json, 
      status_code: :internal_server_error, has_error: true }
 end
```

The code is used in several places by several types of objects. The Interface Segregation principle states that the class should not have methods that are not called by **all** clients.

- How can I use these two principles together for the given example?
- Is Open/Closed principle dependant on Interface Segregation principle, or vice versa?

Comment: Is this method not called by all clients?

Comment: Yes, but parts of this method are not needed for every client. For example, Exception type objects use the first part while others use the second. Interface Segregation states that all clients should call the method the same way.

Comment: Maaaaaahbe this question is a better fit for [programmers.se](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)